# update custom progressBar from other activity continuesly

Tags: android, android-activity, progress-bar

I have 2 `activities`, 1 for `main` and other for custom `progressBar dialog`, I want to start this custom `progressBar` `activity` as `dialog` on button `click` from main `activity`, as it starts it's ok but I need to update the `progressBar` values continuesly, as it comes changing... I tried to create some methods in `progressBar` `activity` also tried to access `progressBar` object as `Static` way but in both cases it throws `exception` of NULL POINTER. Currently I am starting activity as

```
startActivity(new Intent(context, ProgressBar.class));
```

Any help?

**MAIN ACTIVITY**

```
public class UnicornActivity extends Activity implements
    android.view.View.OnClickListener {

Button btnStart;

ProgressDialog prog = new ProgressDialog();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProgressDialog.class));
    ProgressDialog.setMax(1000);
    ProgressDialog.setMessage("it's gonna be fun");
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                ProgressDialog.setProg(i);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
}
```

**PROGRESSBAR ACITIVITY**

```
public class ProgressDialog extends Activity{

static TextView to, till, message;
static ProgressBar progress;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    System.out.println("Inside activity");

    to = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTo);
    till = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTill);
    message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
    progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
}

public static void setProg(int val) {  //NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
    to.setText(val + "");
    progress.setProgress(val);
}

public static void setMax(int val) {   //NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
    till.setText(val + "");
    progress.setMax(val);
}

public static void setMessage(String msg) {   //EXCEPTION
    message.setText(msg);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any reason you have ProgressDialog as an activity?

create a class that extends AsyncTask, make the progress dialog a member, onProgressUpdate call SetProgress.

Comment: does that gives me a custom look I need?

Comment: not related, you can still make ProgressDialog any way you want